# Should I say : "is" or "does"?

Tags: grammaticality, auxiliary-verbs

> Is/Does the file exists?
>
> Are/Do aliens exist?

I think I should use *do,* but there is some case I should use *is*? Also, does that mean something if I use *is*?

Comment: In your first sentence, regardless of the verb at beginning, the last word should be _exist_, not "exists". In interrogative form, the bare infinitive is always used, rather than conjugating the verb..

Comment: If you wanted to use _is_, you'd word it with a "there", like this: _Is there a file? Are there aliens?_

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is helpful to try phrasing the question to an answer like this, and it may become clearer:

is/does the file exist?   The file *does* exist.

are/do aliens exist?  Aliens *do* exist.

If it sounds correct in the answer, that's the word to use in the question.